# Identify similar expressions?

Tags: data-structures, logic

How can I validate two expressions that are **logically equivalent** ? 
For e.g : 
***(a+b) <=> (b+a)*** or ***(a+(b+c)) <=> ((a+b)+c)*** or ***(a && b) <=> (b && a)*** ,etc

I want an **optimize** solution for it, that will identify the duplicate one from 1000s of expressions.

Comment: interesting question. a web search for "equivalent math expressions" yielded a lot of recent scholarly papers, suggesting that this is an open research area. symbolic math packages like Mathematica would probably be a good place to look. restricted domains like polynomials would be easy, but I bet it would get complex fast.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to a comment by @japreiss, there is no open research question here. In the context of propositional expressions like the examples given, logical equivalence is very well understood. (I'm assuming OP is using `+` to mean logical OR rather than numeric addition)

A question for the OP: are you interested in doing this by hand or automating it via programming code?

There are multiple approaches but the one taught in most intro to logic courses and text books would be to construct separate truth tables for the left-hand side and right-hand side, and see if the final values on each row are identical.

If you have a computer system that can already evaluate the truth of an expression like `(a+(b+c))` and `((a+b)+c)`, then that same system can probably be given the whole expression `(a+(b+c)) <=> ((a+b)+c)` and can tell you whether or not it is a tautology.

With regard to comparing 1,000's of expressions to find duplicates, one technique is to convert each expression to [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) and then just use string comparison to see which ones are identical.

Comment: I've to tackle all types of expressions. It can be relational, arithmetic or logical. Evaluating truth table and converting expressions into CNF won't work in case of arithmetic and relational expressions.